# Laravel 5.3 Passport - Vue error: Error when evaluating expression

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

This is giving me a headache for the past two days. I recently updated my laravel application to 5.3, on my local environment I pulled in Laravel/passport. After the installation, everything works as expected.

When I push this update to the production server, everything still works, but vue throws me errors on the passport components. I am still very new to vue and I can't find what is causing this.

The last thing I tried was bringing up a fresh install of Laravel and passport on the production server, which results in the same errors. When I push this installation to my local machine, everything works. I gues this is some kind of dependency error.

These are the errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "token.scopes.length > 0": TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (found in component: <passport-authorized-clients>)
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "token.client.name": TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (found in component: <passport-authorized-clients>)
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "token.scopes.length > 0": TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (found in component: <passport-authorized-clients>)
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "token.client.name": TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (found in component: <passport-authorized-clients>)
```

Has anyone faced the same errors, and how do I fix this?

EDIT: I managed to fix this. I updated php5.6 to php7 and installed the following PHP modules; libgmp-dev, php-gmp. When I did a fresh install again, npm complained about two depencies that passport required; mdanter/ecc and indigophp/hash-compat

Comment: Need some more code here, but seems like you are trying to bind some values that are not there (on `init`, at least). Do you create token as an empty object and then, further down, add the properties? Do you have any element that tries to access this properties on creation?

Comment: I just figured it out. There was a PHP module missing for the OAuth server to work, I don't know why `composer require laravel/passport` did not throw me any errors. But after I installed the PHP module, node gave me another error that it needed `mdanter/ecc and indigophp/hash-compat` to function correctly.

Comment: As I see it, it seemed a client issue [vuejs/vue-resource#317](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/issues/317)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem. The solution [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/laravel-53-passport-vue-error-error-when-evaluating-expression/replies/195467) helped me. It suggests adding the following to `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next ) => {
    next((response) => {
        if( 'Content-Type' in response.headers 
            && response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json' ){
            if( typeof response.data != 'object' ){
                response.data = JSON.parse( response.data );
            }
        }

        if( 'content-type' in response.headers
            && response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json' ){
            if( typeof response.data != 'object' ){
                response.data = JSON.parse( response.data );
            }
        }
    });
});
```